# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorageProvider <- $localStorage <- login

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

hey i'm doing a login in ionic 1... i couldn't save my auth on local storage, before i do this local storage,  i used session storage but everytime people want to open my apps again, it should logged in again..

this is my controllers.

```
.controller('login', function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup, $state, $ionicHistory, $localStorage, $window) {
    // localhost
    var baseUrl = 'http://developing/alhikmah_api/v1/mobile/auth/login';
    $scope.showAlert = function(msg) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: msg.title,
            template: msg.message,
            okText: 'Baik',
            okType: 'button-positive'
        })
    }

    if ($localStorage.getItem('nis') !== null && $localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
        $scope.showAlert({
            title: "Pesan",
            message: "Selamat Datang Kembali :)"
        });
        $state.go('tab.home');
    }
    $scope.login = function() {
        if (!$scope.login.nis) {
            $scope.showAlert({
                title: "Informasi",
                message: "Nomor Induk Santri Harap di Isi !"
            })
        } else if (!$scope.login.pass) {
            $scope.showAlert({
                title: "Informasi",
                message: "password mohon diisi"
            })

        } else {

            $http.post(baseUrl, {
                username: $scope.login.nis,
                password: $scope.login.pass,
                role: "santri"
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.success == false) {
                    $scope.showAlert({
                        title: "Information",
                        message: data.message
                    })
                    $scope.login.nis = '';
                    $scope.login.pass = '';
                } else {
                    $localStorage.setItem('id', data.data[0].id);
                    $localStorage.setItem('nis', data.data[0].username);
                    $localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                    $scope.showAlert({
                        title: "Information",
                        message: data.message
                    })
                    $state.go('tab.home');
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

everything works fine if i use sessionstorage instead of localstorage. But all i want is to make people not log in anymore in my apps.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to **`ngStorage`** module

use **ngStorage** js file like this (make sure you load it after angularjs is loaded, notice the order of script tags) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js>
```

then you can use $localStorage in your controller, if not use  **`$window.localStorage`**

Comment: already use that script and still showing error unknown provider.

Comment: can you provide a plunker

Comment: sorry bruh i still use $localstorage in controllers parameters,  and it works right now after removing that parameters ! thank you !